# Outlook / VBA How can I count the mail I moved by outlook rules?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, email-client, rules, email-server

I have created outlook rules for a shared mailbox. Now, I would like to understand how many of the e-mails are processed through the rules. One of the rules is that an email is moved based on the header or the domain of the sender.

As it is a shared inbox, a count on the emails will be contaminated (people change the header in the mailbox).

I have though of creating a category and assign it automatically to the email. A simple count on the category will do the trick (I can do this with basic VBA code). However, categories are client sided and not server sided rules. This does thus not work.

Does anyone have another suggestion on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it like this, for anyone that is interested:

I forward the e-mail to my personal email. Based on this new folder, I can do the count :)